# Advanced search option for close votes

Tags: feature-request, search

Is there an advanced search option for detecting questions with/without close votes (BEFORE a question is closed)?

I'm aware of `closed:0` but I would also like to avoid/locate questions (usually avoid to be honest) where others have indicated it should be closed.

Comment: AFAIK, only SEDE can give you that information.

Comment: FYI you dont have to submit an answer for the uploaded image to be saved. Once you upload it to the draft, it's uploaded; no need to post.

Comment: We also have a bot that allows us to search on cv and find duplicates in real-time [SOCVFinder](https://stackapps.com/q/6910/39409) it is available in the [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) room, you are welcome to step by and try it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [the Magic Tag userscript Tiny Giant wrote](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/MagicTagReview.user.js). Allows you to search a tag by how many close/delete votes it has ([Version 2](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/MagicTagReview2.user.js) is in beta)

There's no native way AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, no idea what that js does or how to use it, but the major take home is: What I would like does not exist, So be it. Cheers.

Comment: @Used_By_Already You need to install tampermonkey on Chrome (or greasemonkey on Firefox) and when you add that userscript to it, it will run that JS on top of StackOverflow.